# What is the best approach to rank a dictionary of objects?

Tags: python, sorting, rank

Given the following classes:

```
class Comparison():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.rank = 0

class Comparisons(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Comparisons, self).__init__()

    def rank(self):
        # Method to examine each Comparison instance and
        # assign Comparison.rank based on Comparison.value
```

What is an efficient way for the `rank()` method to examine the objects and assign a rank? For example:

```
comparisons = Comparisons()

# store some Comparison instances
comparisons['one'] = Comparison(10)
comparisons['two'] = Comparison(5)
comparisons['three'] = Comparison(1)

# function to rank the comparisons
comparisons.rank()

print(comparisons['one'].rank)
print(comparisons['two'].rank)
print(comparisons['three'].rank)
```

Returns:

```
3
2
1
```

If the `rank()` method could handle ties, that would be even more beneficial.

Comment: You don't need to subclass the built-in `dict` class to sort them because regular dictionaries can be sorted. Are creating a subclass for some other reason and if so, what are they?

Comment: @martineau To be able to implement the `.rank()` method?

Comment: @martineau Selcuk is right.  That is why I subclassed the built-in.

Comment: @martineau It only appears that because you have (incorrectly) edited the question.

Comment: @martineau Just rolled it back. You had changed `comparisons = Comparisons()` to `comparisons = Comparison()`.

Comment: @martineau Not sure what you mean by _"there is no `Comparisons` class"_.

Comment: @Selcuk: OK, sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the most intuitive (naive?) way:

```
def rank(self):
    sorted_comparisons = sorted(self.values(), key=lambda c: c.value)
    for rank, comparison in enumerate(sorted_comparisons, 1):
        comparison.rank = rank
```

Comment: just curious, but why do you say the naive way?

Comment: Because this is _probably_ not the most efficient way of doing it. That being said, it is _probably_ reasonable for not-so-huge datasets. See [Naive algoritms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_(disambiguation)#Mathematics,_computer_science).